# Keyboard layout reverts at every boot

Tags: 12.10, gnome, keyboard-layout, gdm

I am using 12.10 with Gnome 3. I changed LightDM to GDM. When I boot up keyboard layout changes to default US layout. When I add another layout to end of list at Region settings my selected layout becomes active. What should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I entered this command at terminal to get my current keyboard layout that I set after every boot

```
setxkbmap -query
```

result:

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     tr
```

I created a script that includes this line `setxkbmap <layout>`, in my case `setxkbmap tr`. I added this script to startup programs. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 8):

I also have the same problem. I did a lot of research, but I have not found a solution for me. Instead, for many people, this was the solution:

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `sudo vim /etc/default/keyboard`
3. The values ​​within the file should be as follows:

   ```
   XKBMODEL="pc105"
   XKBLAYOUT="it"
   XKBVARIANT=""
   XKBOPTIONS=""
   ```
4. `XKBLAYOUT` is the code of your keyboard layout. Type `man xkeyboard-config` for shows the codes for keyboard model and layout.
5. exit

Reboot and check. I hope this is the right solution for you too ;)

Answer (score 5):

This (the second, not the first) solution definitely works. I had the same problem with the US layout I wanted to use and kept having to remove and readd each time I logged into Ubuntu 13.04. It kept reverting back to the UK Keyboard layout, despite having run:

`dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

(EVEN WHEN THE LANGUAGE ICON ON THE TOP RIGHT OF THE SCREEN ACTUALLY SAYS 'en US') so this is definitely a serious bug as even changing keyboard layouts by clicking on them is completely unresponsive! Hope there will be some kind of fix for this soon.

Anyway, I found that, in fact, simply typing the command:

> setxkbmap

into the 'Startup Applications' command tab solves the problem of Ubuntu forgetting the keyboard layout settings upon each boot.

HOWEVER: I did discover something else: If you are also running `xmodmap` in startup, then it will be OVERWRITTEN by the `setxkbmap` command. The `setxkbmap` command thus overrides the `xmodmap` commands at startup. (I found this out because I had finally succeeded in getting Ubuntu to remember my keybinding of Scroll Lock (which I use for my backlit keyboard) by means of running an `.Xmodmap` file including the modification (in my case：

> add mod3 = Scroll_Lock

Would be nice if anyone has any ideas on how to be able to run both on startup, at least until there is a permanent fix for the very very common, obvious and serious language layout problem in Ubuntu (i.e. Ubuntu forgetting keyboard layout settings after every boot).

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Terminal by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
2. Login with root, `su`
3. Enter Pass
4. Type `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`
5. exit

Reboot and recheck. Let us know if this solves your problem.

Comment: It didnt solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

After an update to 14.4 using awesome as windowmanager I ran into the very same issue.

Now I execute "setxkbmap de" (for german layout)  in the configuration-file ~/.config.rc.lua and anything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my startup application preferences and noticed Fcitx was being run by default in the start. I then configured Fcitx for my layout and got it fixed.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution:

1. Open Terminal
2. Login with root `su`
3. Enter password of root
4. Update and Upgrade all with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
5. Type the following:

   ```
   apt-get install console-data
   apt-get install console-setup
   apt-get install console-locales
   apt-get install keyboard-configuration
   ```
6. Reboot and recheck.

Comment: Why "Login with root su" and after that `sudo ...` and why reboot?

Comment: Yes , `sudo` can be avoided . I had read that it was enough to logout and then login , but for me it worked only after the restart.

Answer (score -1):

I have Ubuntu 10.04, and I have a same problem!

The follow fix works for me:

Logout of your current session.

Click on your username. At bottom bar: there is a combo <-- switch to language correct

That's all!