# Keyboard layout changes to English after each reboot

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, reboot

Recently I upgraded my Ubuntu to 14.04 and now my keyboard layout changes to "English (US)" each time I reboot, even though in the top right of my screen "German (Swiss)" is selected as the active keyboard. My list of selected keyboards shows "German (Swiss)", "Russian", "Greek" and "English (US)", in this order, where "German (Swiss)" should be the default setting.

Does anyone know how this problem can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, I think it's a  [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-keyboard/+bug/1240198). You can find more info here [Keyboard layout reverts at every boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282283/keyboard-layout-reverts-at-every-boot)

You can add a startup command to switch back to your keyboard layout like

```
setxkbmap ch
```

List of keyboard layouts [here](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Configuration_du_clavier_apr%C3%A8s_l%27installation)